# Linear Regression in R: Need to convert categorical variables to factor or character?

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data

I'm running a linear regression in R.

If i have an independent variable `Gender` with only values 0 (for Male) and 1 (for Female), do i need to convert them to factor or character?

What is going to be the impact on my analysis?

Comment: If it's already coded as 0/1 there's no need to make it a factor but neither is there any harm in making it a factor.

Answer (score 5):

A factor variable with `n` levels, are represented as `n - 1` binary variables. Thus if this categorical variable is already 0-1 binary, then there is no need to code it as factor variable.

The only subtle issue, is the meaning of 0 and 1. Consider the following example:

```
## raw binary variable
set.seed(0); x <- sample(0:1, 8, replace = TRUE)
```

Without coding it into a factor, we have a model matrix:

```
> model.matrix(~x)
  (Intercept) x
1           1 1
2           1 0
3           1 0
4           1 1
5           1 1
6           1 0
7           1 1
8           1 1
```

Now, if we code it into a factor, there are two ways of coding:

```
x1 <- factor(x, levels = c(0, 1))
x2 <- factor(x, levels = c(1, 0))
```

R will drop the first level for contrasting, so the model matrix generated are slightly different:

```
model.matrix(~ x1)
  (Intercept) x11  ## x11 means level 1 of variable x1
1           1   1
2           1   0
3           1   0
4           1   1
5           1   1
6           1   0
7           1   1
8           1   1

> model.matrix(~ x2)
  (Intercept) x20  ## x20 means level 0 of variable x1
1           1   0
2           1   1
3           1   1
4           1   0
5           1   0
6           1   1
7           1   0
8           1   0
```

Representations are equivalent, but interpretation of the resulting coefficients will be different.

Comment: I'm sorry @ZheyuanLi. "*there is no need to code it as factor variable*" is not technically correct. The regression needs to know if the variables are actual quantitative variables or categorical ones. The only way I know to mark the variable as categorical ones is to turn them into factors.

Comment: @pbahr His categorical variable is already 0-1 binary.

Comment: Does "For your information" add anything of value to this answer? If not I suggest removing it because it may be viewed as impolite.

Comment: @Ista thanks. I receive such kind of comment with "FYI" often, so thought it means no harm. Hehe, now I know it does mean something. Sorry English is not my first language.

Comment: The first sentence says it _is_ represented but I think it might be better to say it _can be_ since there are other ways of considering contrasts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn the categorical variables into `factor` for the regression to deal with them as such. `contrasts()` can be used to check the way R thinks about the base level, against which other levels are compared. `relevel()` can be used to change the base level if needed.